# Android: Intent Received if - else

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create activities which directs back to the home page and pump up the home page screen, with "Database is now updated". However, I have no idea how to pump up the toast, only when the intent is received. BUT I am not sure how to well received the Intent, here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView time;
Button viewStock, descriptionSearch;
String lastUpdateStandard = "Last Update Time: ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewStock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detailSearchButton);
    descriptionSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.descriptionSearchButton);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    // retrieve time from database to see last update time
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> lastUpdateTime = db.getLastUpdate();
    time.setText(lastUpdateStandard + lastUpdateTime.get(0));

    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    /**
     *
     * What should I write if there is no received Intent? 
     * Probably I need an if-else statement, but I have no idea how it should be made. 
     */
}
```

Comment: Your design is wrong. You are calling a db operation in the main UI thread. This operation could be really long in some situation, your app could be killed by the OS with an ANR.

Comment: so if I want to get something from database and present it out when the page is launched, what should I do? If this is the .MainActivity class?

Comment: Use a separate thread, an intentservice, an asyncTask or whatever you want but avoid to do db operation on the main thread. In this case maybe a simple asynctask would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of check you currently want to do is not suggested as all activities are started by an intent (Android was designed this way), they will always return an intent. What you should instead be doing is to check if the intent used to start the activity has the data you wish to extract. You obviously will be requiring the intent only because you need some kind of a data from the intent correct? So instead of checking if an intent is returned, you should check for whatever extra you are getting from the intent. for example, if you wanted to extract the extra with the the string "hello" as key , you will be using:

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
if(receivedIntent.getStringExtra("hello") != null) {
    // Means the intent has the data you expect
} else {
    // It does not have the data you expect
    // Do some processing here
}
```

If you were to check if an intent was received, you will always get a value back